# NullpointerException using getSupportfrgamnetmanager

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmentmanager

In my application I'm using pageviewer with two tabs. In each tab I populate view with some data after calling aysnctask. Also the fragment which contains these tab and viewpager have filter in it which filter the content of my view accordingly. Also I'm using Recycleview for populating data. On click of item of recycleview I open new fragment. The problem I'm facing is that when app is open first time , after data when I open my fragment on click events using getsupportFragmentmanager it working fine But when I change my data content using filter, when I click on item to open fragment using getsupportFragmentmanager it gives me following error.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.getSupportFragmentManager()' on a null object reference
```

ParentFragment code is here :

```
public class TabB extends Fragment {
ViewPager viewPager;
TabLayout tabLayout;
Clubs clubs = new Clubs();
Events events = new Events();
private static RecyclerView Genre;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
public static JSONArray jsonArrayResult = new JSONArray();
public static final String[] IMAGE_NAME = {"allevent", "rock", "jazz", "house", "bass", "chill","bollywood","commerial", "karaoke","sufi"};
ArrayList<Integer> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
public static String Genrename = IMAGE_NAME[0];
public static GenreAdapter genreAdapter;
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View RootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tabb, container, false);
    viewPager = (ViewPager) RootView.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    tabLayout = (TabLayout) RootView.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    Genre = (RecyclerView)RootView.findViewById(R.id.rvImages);
    for (int i=0;i< IMAGE_NAME.length;i++){
        String imageFileName = IMAGE_NAME[i];
        int imgResId = getResources().getIdentifier(imageFileName, "drawable", "in.catalystapp.catalyst");
        arrayList.add(imgResId);
    }
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(),LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
    Genre.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    genreAdapter = new GenreAdapter(arrayList, getActivity());
    Genre.setAdapter(genreAdapter);
    TabBviewPagerAdapter tabBviewPagerAdapter = new TabBviewPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(),"allevent");
    viewPager.setAdapter(tabBviewPagerAdapter);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    genreAdapter.SetOnItemClickListener(new GenreAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void OnItemClick(View view, int position) {
            FilterGenres( IMAGE_NAME[position], new PageviewCaller() {
                @Override
                public void PopulatePageViewer(String key) {
                    Log.d("key", key);
                    clubs.PopulateClubList(key);
                    events.FilterEvents(key);
                }
            });
        }
    });
    return RootView;
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();

    try {
        Field childFragmentManager = Fragment.class.getDeclaredField("mChildFragmentManager");
        childFragmentManager.setAccessible(true);
        childFragmentManager.set(this, null);

    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

public void FilterGenres(String key,PageviewCaller pageviewCaller){
    pageviewCaller.PopulatePageViewer(key);
}
```

one of child frgament code is here :

```
public class Clubs extends Fragment {
static ArrayList<ClubItem> mClubItems = new ArrayList<>();
static RecyclerView Clubcards;
static RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
static ClubsAdapter clubsAdapter;
static Context context;
public String mKey;
Parcelable liststate;
static JSONArray jsonClubs = new JSONArray();

public Clubs(){}
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View RootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.clubs, container, false);
    Log.d("clubs-life-cycle","oncreate");
    Clubcards = (RecyclerView)RootView.findViewById(R.id.clubcard);
    context = getActivity();
    Bundle args = getArguments();
    mKey = args.getString("key");
    new GetClubDetails().execute();
    return RootView;
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    Log.d("liststate", "saving listview state @ onPause");
    liststate = layoutManager.onSaveInstanceState();
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    if (liststate != null){
        layoutManager.onRestoreInstanceState(liststate);
    } else {

    }
}

public class GetClubDetails extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Void> {
    JSONObject jsonresult = new JSONObject();
    ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute(){
        super.onPreExecute();
        progressDialog.setMessage("Fetching Feeds....");
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        RESTfulAPI resTfulAPI = new RESTfulAPI();
        jsonresult = resTfulAPI.getJSONfromurl("api/clubs/","GET","");
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        if (jsonresult!=null){
            Log.d("json", jsonresult.toString());
            try {
                jsonClubs = jsonresult.getJSONArray("datasets");
                PopulateClubList("allevent");
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();

    try {
        Field childFragmentManager = Fragment.class.getDeclaredField("mChildFragmentManager");
        childFragmentManager.setAccessible(true);
        childFragmentManager.set(this, null);

    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

public void PopulateClubList(String key){
    mClubItems = new ArrayList<>();
    clubsAdapter = null;
    for (int i=0;i < jsonClubs.length();i++){
        try {
            if (key.equals("allevent") || key.equals(jsonClubs.getJSONObject(i).getString("genre")) ){
                mClubItems.add(new ClubItem(jsonClubs.getJSONObject(i).getString("clubName"),jsonClubs.getJSONObject(i).getString("address")));
                clubsAdapter = new ClubsAdapter(mClubItems,context);
                layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context);
                Clubcards.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
                Clubcards.setAdapter(clubsAdapter);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    clubsAdapter.SetOnItemClickListener(new ClubsAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void OnItemClick(View view, int position) {
            getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out).add(R.id.main_content, new Clubdetails()).addToBackStack(null).commit();
        }
    });
}
```

What I'm Doing Wrong?

Comment: Check your imports, are you sure you're importing the support fragment in each fragment?

Comment: Seems like your fragment is detached and activity is null

Comment: Please post stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

This May cause Because You are Importing different version of Fragment.

Because there are two types of `Fragment`.

**1** `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`

and

**2** `android.app.Fragment`;

Make sure  you're importing the same `Fragment` in each Fragmnet class or Activities.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try to use `getFragmentManager()` instead of `getSupportFragmentManager()` ?

Maybe it due to your version of appcompat library